# Organization of S920 (I420 planar) format

Tags: video, webcam, yuv

Currently I am working with a webcam that supports 3 formats according to `v4l2-ctl --list-formats`:

```
Index       : 0
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'S920'
Name        : GSPCA SN9C20X I420

Index       : 1
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'BA81'
Name        : 8-bit Bayer BGBG/GRGR

Index       : 2
Type        : Video Capture
Pixel Format: 'JPEG' (compressed)
Name        : JFIF JPEG
```

The JPEG is working fine.
The problem arises when I wanted to work with the I420 raw data.
I'm doing 640x480. and it does return correct number of bytes. which is 460800 (640x480x1.5). But after whole day of experiment I still cannot get how it is organized.

Looks like it returns in blocks of pixels, which is 128 (192 bytes).
If I cover the cam I can see that the first 128(y components) bytes are small, and followed by 64 larger bytes. Therefore I assume it's 128 y, followed by 32 u, and 32 v.

Here is a sample `hexdump -n 200` when I covered the webcam:

```
0000000 2b2b 2c2b 2e2b 2e2d 2b2b 2c2b 2c2b 2d2c 
0000010 2b2b 2b2b 2b2a 2c2b 2b2b 2b2c 2b2a 2b2c 
0000020 2b2a 2c2b 2b2b 2b2b 2a2a 2b2b 2b2b 2b2c 
0000030 2a2a 2c2b 2b2b 2c2b 2b2c 2c2b 2b2b 2b2b 
0000040 2d2d 2c2c 2c2c 2d2c 2c2d 2c2d 2c2d 2c2c 
0000050 2c2c 2b2b 2c2c 2c2c 2c2c 2b2c 2c2c 2c2c 
0000060 2b2b 2b2b 2b2b 2c2b 2b2c 2c2c 2b2c 2c2c 
0000070 2c2b 2c2b 2c2b 2c2b 2b2b 2c2c 2c2d 2c2b 
0000080 7a7a 7b79 7c79 7a7a 7979 797a 797a 787a
0000090 7a7a 797a 7a77 797a 797a 797a 7978 797a 
00000a0 7e7e 7d7e 7f7e 7f7f 7e7e 7e7f 7e7f 7e7f 
00000b0 7d7e 7e7d 7e7e 7e7e 7e7f 7e7e 7e7e 7e7e
00000c0 2d2c 2c2c 2d2c 2f2d
```

However, after trial and error I still could not find how these components map into the whole 640x480.
I tried to convert this into yuy2 as follows:

y0 u0 y1 v0 y2 u0 y3 v0, y4 u1 y5 v1 y6 u1 y7 v1

but looks like it's not..
I googled but did not see much people work with this format. Any people have experience using this yuv format?

Update:
The closest image I can get is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz9G05et_k8fOS0zLUNkMXpYalU/view?usp=sharing I used use 16x8 pixel per block, since S920 outputs 128 pixel per block(I assume, based on the pattern I saw). And after some trial and error I think 16x8 is the closest.

Comment: `IYUV`is `W*H` bytes Y followed by `W*H/4` bytes Cb (U), followed by `W*H/4` bytes Cr (V). If you can upload an example file somewhere I can have a look...

Comment: Thanks for your interest Fred. Here is a link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz9G05et_k8faTJMVDdYa3dmdlU/view?usp=sharing . I was also expecting a file with 640x480 bytes followed by 640x480/4 u and v. But you can see from the file every 192 bytes has a pattern.. The image is webcam cover by my thumb therefore most dark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this was fun :-)
It turns out that the GSPCA SN9C20X I42 format it's just some variation of yuv420, actually it's yuv420 but frame is broken into tiles.

I found this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microdia/krYWLHDaYSQ/96xTWR_ayOgJ) that lead me in the right direction.

The output image looks like this
[image]

This is the C-code used for converting it to IYUV, which I got from [github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/philips/libv4l/master/libv4lconvert/sn9c20x.c) and modified slightly with a main-function:

```
/*
 * Sonix SN9C20X decoder
 * Vasily Khoruzhick, (C) 2008-2009
 * Algorithm based on Java code written by Jens on microdia google group
 *
 * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
 * along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
 *
 * Note this code was originally licensed under the GNU GPL instead of the
 * GNU LGPL, its license has been changed by its author.
 */

//#include "libv4lconvert-priv.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>



#define DO_SANITY_CHECKS 0

static const int UVTranslate[32] = {0, 1, 2, 3,
            8, 9, 10, 11,
            16, 17, 18, 19,
            24, 25, 26, 27,
            4, 5, 6, 7,
            12, 13, 14, 15,
            20, 21, 22, 23,
            28, 29, 30, 31};

static const int Y_coords_624x[128][2] = {
{ 0,  0}, { 1,  0}, { 2,  0}, { 3,  0}, { 4,  0}, { 5,  0}, { 6,  0}, { 7,  0},
{ 0,  1}, { 1,  1}, { 2,  1}, { 3,  1}, { 4,  1}, { 5,  1}, { 6,  1}, { 7,  1},
{ 0,  2}, { 1,  2}, { 2,  2}, { 3,  2}, { 4,  2}, { 5,  2}, { 6,  2}, { 7,  2},
{ 0,  3}, { 1,  3}, { 2,  3}, { 3,  3}, { 4,  3}, { 5,  3}, { 6,  3}, { 7,  3},

{ 0,  4}, { 1,  4}, { 2,  4}, { 3,  4}, { 4,  4}, { 5,  4}, { 6,  4}, { 7,  4},
{ 0,  5}, { 1,  5}, { 2,  5}, { 3,  5}, { 4,  5}, { 5,  5}, { 6,  5}, { 7,  5},
{ 0,  6}, { 1,  6}, { 2,  6}, { 3,  6}, { 4,  6}, { 5,  6}, { 6,  6}, { 7,  6},
{ 0,  7}, { 1,  7}, { 2,  7}, { 3,  7}, { 4,  7}, { 5,  7}, { 6,  7}, { 7,  7},

{ 8,  0}, { 9,  0}, {10,  0}, {11,  0}, {12,  0}, {13,  0}, {14,  0}, {15,  0},
{ 8,  1}, { 9,  1}, {10,  1}, {11,  1}, {12,  1}, {13,  1}, {14,  1}, {15,  1},
{ 8,  2}, { 9,  2}, {10,  2}, {11,  2}, {12,  2}, {13,  2}, {14,  2}, {15,  2},
{ 8,  3}, { 9,  3}, {10,  3}, {11,  3}, {12,  3}, {13,  3}, {14,  3}, {15,  3},

{ 8,  4}, { 9,  4}, {10,  4}, {11,  4}, {12,  4}, {13,  4}, {14,  4}, {15,  4},
{ 8,  5}, { 9,  5}, {10,  5}, {11,  5}, {12,  5}, {13,  5}, {14,  5}, {15,  5},
{ 8,  6}, { 9,  6}, {10,  6}, {11,  6}, {12,  6}, {13,  6}, {14,  6}, {15,  6},
{ 8,  7}, { 9,  7}, {10,  7}, {11,  7}, {12,  7}, {13,  7}, {14,  7}, {15,  7}
};

static void do_write_u(const unsigned char *buf, unsigned char *ptr,
    int i, int j)
{
    *ptr = buf[i + 128 + j];
}

static void do_write_v(const unsigned char *buf, unsigned char *ptr,
    int i, int j)
{
    *ptr = buf[i + 160 + j];
}

void v4lconvert_sn9c20x_to_yuv420(const unsigned char *raw, unsigned char *i420,
  int width, int height, int yvu)
{
    int i = 0, x = 0, y = 0, j, relX, relY, x_div2, y_div2;
    const unsigned char *buf = raw;
    unsigned char *ptr;
    int frame_size = width * height;
    int frame_size_div2 = frame_size >> 1;
    int frame_size_div4 = frame_size >> 2;
    int width_div2 = width >> 1;
    int height_div2 = height >> 1;
    void (*do_write_uv1)(const unsigned char *buf, unsigned char *ptr, int i,
    int j) = NULL;
    void (*do_write_uv2)(const unsigned char *buf, unsigned char *ptr, int i,
    int j) = NULL;

    if (yvu) {
        do_write_uv1 = do_write_v;
        do_write_uv2 = do_write_u;
    }
    else {
        do_write_uv1 = do_write_u;
        do_write_uv2 = do_write_v;
    }

    while (i < (frame_size + frame_size_div2)) {
        for (j = 0; j < 128; j++) {
            relX = x + Y_coords_624x[j][0];
            relY = y + Y_coords_624x[j][1];

#if (DO_SANITY_CHECKS==1)
            if ((relX < width) && (relY < height)) {
#endif
                ptr = i420 + relY * width + relX;
                *ptr = buf[i + j];
#if (DO_SANITY_CHECKS==1)
            }
#endif

        }
        x_div2 = x >> 1;
        y_div2 = y >> 1;
        for (j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
            relX = (x_div2) + (j & 0x07);
            relY = (y_div2) + (j >> 3);

#if (DO_SANITY_CHECKS==1)
            if ((relX < width_div2) && (relY < height_div2)) {
#endif
                ptr = i420 + frame_size +
                    relY * width_div2 + relX;
                do_write_uv1(buf, ptr, i, j);
                ptr += frame_size_div4;
                do_write_uv2(buf, ptr, i, j);
#if (DO_SANITY_CHECKS==1)
            }
#endif
        }

        i += 192;
        x += 16;
        if (x >= width) {
            x = 0;
            y += 8;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int cnt;
    FILE* fd;
    size_t size = 640*480*3/2;

    fd = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!fd) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening %s\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    uint8_t* raw = malloc(size*sizeof(uint8_t));
    uint8_t* out = malloc(size*sizeof(uint8_t));

    if (!raw || !out) {
        goto cleanup;
    }

    fread(raw, sizeof(uint8_t), size, fd);
    fclose(fd);

    v4lconvert_sn9c20x_to_yuv420(raw, out, 640, 480, 0);

    fd = fopen("out_640x480.yuv", "wb");
    if (!fd) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening %s\n", argv[1]);
        goto cleanup;
    }
    fwrite(out, sizeof(uint8_t), size, fd);

cleanup:
    free(raw);
    free(out);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Hi Fred.. This is fantastic. This agrees with what I thought with 16x8 "tile". However, it looks like the Y component is further divided into 2 8x8 tiles. Let me try to modify my own code to  see if I could make it work later today... Thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry dude i did not know how to do that. I think i just did